# How to deal with access tokens on apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

In several apache beam pipelines I want to implement, I need to make http calls to another service within the same app engine project.
The way we typically deal with this is by getting an access token, and refreshing it every time it expires (say, every hour).

In apache beam, however, I cannot really define a class that returns/refreshes an access token and is reachable from within a ParDo.
I could of course get a new one every time I enter the process() part of a DoFn, but this seems terrible performance-wise.

Is there a recommended way to deal with this problem? I was thinking of maybe using side inputs, but I'm not sure if this really solves it.

(If at all possible, the solution should work for both streaming and batch jobs)

In case this is relevant (but shouldn't, I guess), I am working with the python sdk.

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud Dataflow? Did you try setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key? This documentation might be worth looking into: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

Comment: I am using google cloud dataflow. If I understand correctly, setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is only going to help me if I want to access "built-in" google cloud services (say storage, big query...), not our own microservices on the app engine. I may be wrong about this.
Anyway, I finally found a solution that works perfectly for me: using the start_bundle() method of a DoFn, that allows me to get or refresh a token for a whole bundle of elements. Took me some time to find it as it is not really prominent in the documentation.